# WUSA 2359302 Error Code when installing WMF silent

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-7, wmf

I'm trying to add WMF via WUSA.exe to use powershell 3.0 on Windows 7. This to rename a computer, because I don't find the right NETDOM.Exe installer, and the WMI command doesn't work.

The WUSA silent installer gives me the 2359302 error.

What does this mean?

.Net 4.0 is already installed.

Answer (score 9):

2359302 converts to 0x00240006 (which should be in the update log) and it means the patch is already applied according to this page. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938205

Comment: Unfortunately it appears Microsoft has updated that page since you posted and no longer lists that error code. Stack Overflow questions like this one are one of the few ways to find out what this code means. :P